# How to fix Circular import error in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I started coding a music bot using discord.py, but when I run the program, It gives me this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from partially initialized module 'music' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/music/__init__.py)
```

Here is the code:

```
import music
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands

cogs=[music]

client = commands.Bot (command_prefix= "|", intents = discord.intends.all()) 

for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(client)

class music(commands.cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  @commands.command()
  async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel!")
      voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
      if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
      else:
          await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

          @commands.command()
          async def dissconnect(self,ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.dissconnect()

            @commands.command()
            async def play(self,ctx,url):
              ctx.voice_client.stop()
              FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
              YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
              vc = ctx.voice_client

              with youtube_dl.YoutubeDl(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
                url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
                source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe[url2,--FFMPEG_OPTIONS] #try n
                vc.play(source)

              @commands.command()
              async def pause(self, ctx):
               ctx.voice_client.pause()
              await ctx.send("Paused ⏸️")
    
              @commands.command()
              async def resume(self, ctx):
               ctx.voice_client.resume()
              await ctx.send("Resumed ▶️")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

The code above was written in another file. I wrote some code in the main file so it could run this file.
I even renamed the file which had the same name of that of the module, but that also does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `music` module you're trying to import has a bug in which it tries to import part of itself. You could report this on its GitHub repo. You could try installing a different version of the library or using a different library for your needs.

As a side note, it's probably ill advised to name a class the same thing as a library that you're importing to prevent namespace clashes.